# How to detect hidden component in React

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, rendering

In brief,

I have a infinite scroll list who render for each Item 5 PureComponent.

My idea is to somehow, only render the 5 PureComponent if the Item is visible.

The question is,

> How to detect if the Item component is visible for the user or not?

Comment: Do you mean that components which are not visible in the viewport will not be part of the DOM?

Comment: well the Item component will still be here, but not the 5 other PureComponent included in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution:

add `scrollPosition` and `containerSize` to `this.state`

create `ref` to container in `render()`

`<div ref={cont => { this.scrollContainer = cont; }} />`

in `componentDidMount()` subscribe to `scroll` event

`this.scrollContainer.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)`

in `componentWillUnmount()` unsubscribe

`this.scrollContainer.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)`

your `handleScroll` should look sth like

```
handleScroll (e) {
    const { target: { scrollTop, clientHeight } } = e;
    this.setState(state => ({...state, scrollPosition: scrollTop, containerSize: clientHeight}))
}
```

and then in your render function just check which element should be displayed and render correct ones `numOfElementsToRender = state.containerSize / elementSize` and `firstElementIndex = state.scrollPosition / elementSize - 1`

when you have all this just render your list of elements and apply filter base on element's `index` or however you want to sort them

Ofc you need to handle all edge cases and add bufor for smooth scrolling (20% of height should be fine)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Intersection_observer_options) with a polyfill (it's chrome 61+) . It's a more performant way (in new browsers) to look for intersections, and in other cases, it falls back to piro's answer. They also let you specify a threshold at which the intersection becomes true. Check this out:

https://github.com/researchgate/react-intersection-observer

```
import React from 'react';
import 'intersection-observer'; // optional polyfill
import Observer from '@researchgate/react-intersection-observer';

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    handleIntersection(event) {
        console.log(event.isIntersecting); // true if it gets cut off
    }

    render() {
        const options = {
            onChange: this.handleIntersection,
            root: "#scrolling-container",
            rootMargin: "0% 0% -25%"
        };

        return (
            <div id="scrolling-container" style={{ overflow: 'scroll', height: 100 }}>
                <Observer {...options}>
                    <div>
                        I am the target element
                    </div>
                </Observer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```